# VSCode unable to sign commits

Tags: git, environment-variables, visual-studio-code, gnupg

If I try to commit something, I'm getting this error.

```
> git -c user.useConfigOnly=true commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file - -S
error: gpg failed to sign the data:
gpg: skipped <redacted>: No secret key
[GNUPG:] INV_SGNR 9 <redacted>
[GNUPG:] FAILURE sign 17
gpg: signing failed: No secret key

fatal: failed to write commit object
```

Commits work normally from external terminals. It was failing in the embedded terminal in Code, but it works correctly now after I added `export GNUPGHOME=/home/use/.local/share/gnupg` in `.bashrc`.

I recently moved the gpg files from `/home/user/.gnupg` to the location specified in `$GNUPGHOME` above. Looks like while trying to sign the commit, Code isn't picking up that environment variable from `.bashrc` even though the embedded terminal does pick it up. Can anyone help me to get it to work?

Comment: I am also experiencing this and receive similar but it is complaining about `gpg: signing failed: No pinentry`.

I have set in my shell profile (fish):
`set -Ux GPG_TTY $(tty)`
`set -Ux PINENTRY_USER_DATA_DIR $HOME/.gnupg`

In `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` I have:
`use-agent`
`default-key XXX`

And in `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` I have:
`default-cache-ttl 28800`
`pinentry-program "/usr/bin/pinentry-gnome3"`

Nothing seems to work from VSCode. From the CLI and command prompt in VSCode I can commit and push and get the GUI for GPG but not through the Git view in VSCode

Comment: Were you able to fix this?

Comment: @the_real_one No, unfortunately. I switched my workflow to neovim, so that kind of fixed it I guess.

Comment: @the_real_one BTW, does setting `pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-tty` in your `gpg-agent.conf` help?

Comment: I am not at my machine but my suspicion is VScode wouldn’t throw the prompt? I will try though and recomment on findings